Radian runs the wrong version of R in both VScode and the terminal
I am trying to run the last version of R (4.4.2) with radian, but for whatever reason, radian is still pointing to the older version (4.4.1).
I tried the solution reported here without any success (note that I did not uninstall the previous version of R, at least not yet).
Surprisingly, when I type in R:
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R"
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31)"

and when I type in radian:
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R"
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)"

so both agree on R_HOME, but run a different version of R.
Then, in the terminal I also tried:
> radian --version
radian version: 0.6.13
r executable: /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R
r version: 4.4.2
python executable: /usr/bin/python3
python version: 3.10.12

Finally, radian --r-binary=/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R still runs R 4.4.1, despite the command /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R itself starts R 4.4.2. I am therefore confused and could not find anything online.
Finally, when I type in the shell:
which -a R
/usr/local/bin/R
/usr/local/bin/R

which lists twice /usr/local/bin/R. When I execute it, I again starts R 4.4.2.
What follows might be important:
I installed R 4.4.2 from source, while (I think, but I do not remember) R 4.4.1 was installed with apt-get install. I decided to compile from source because of a problem with Quarto not managing transparency
> cat .Rprofile
if (interactive() && Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "") {
  Sys.setenv(TERM_PROGRAM = "vscode")
  source(file.path(Sys.getenv(
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "USERPROFILE" else "HOME"
  ), ".vscode-R", "init.R"))
}

where the file ~/.vscode-R/init.R seems to check whether the packages rlang and jsonlite are installed or not for VScode and do other stuff, but does not influence which version of R is running (at least from what I understood, I read it fast...)

What do you get when you run type R on the terminal?

@KonradRudolph Hello, type R returns: /usr/local/bin/R
